# how to reset shopping cart value in drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to reset value if user press reset button in below jsfiddle please help me

if user drag and drop the values and then press reset then it again display blank box and reset all values please help me to solve this

HTML

Exercise1:

```
<div id="products">
  <div class="ui-widget-content">


    <li data-id="1" class = "bank" id="seven" >
      <a href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;" class="button button-green">
        my
      </a>

    </li>
    <li data-id="3" class="bank" id="third">
      <a href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;" class="button button-orange">
        new 
      </a>
    </li>


    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" border=1>
            <tr>
              <td  width : '33%'>
                <div id="shoppingCart1" class="shoppingCart">
                  <div align="center" class="ui-widget-content">
                    <ol id="amt1" style="list-style:none">
                      <li class="placeholder">
                        &nbsp;
                      </li>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div id="shoppingCart2" class="shoppingCart">
                  <div align="center" class="ui-widget-content">
                    <ol id="amt2" style="list-style:none">
                      <li class="placeholder">
                        &nbsp;
                      </li>
                    </ol>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <br/>

          <br/>


          <input type="button" value="reset" class="reset"/>
          <br/>

          <br/>

          <br/>
```

Jquery

```
$("#products li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"

});
$("#shoppingCart1 ol").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ".bank",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var self = $(this);
        self.find(".placeholder").remove();


        var productid = ui.draggable.attr("data-id");
        if (self.find("[data-id=" + productid + "]").length) return;
        var listItem = $("<li></li>", {
            "text": ui.draggable.text(),
            "data-id": productid

        });

        var cartid = self.closest('.shoppingCart').attr('value');
        $(".shoppingCart:not(#" + cartid + ") [data-id=" + productid + "]").remove();

        self.html(listItem);




    }
});
$("#shoppingCart2 ol").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    accept: ".bank",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var self = $(this);
        self.find(".placeholder").remove();

        var productid = ui.draggable.attr("data-id");
        if (self.find("[data-id=" + productid + "]").length) return;
        var listItem = $("<li></li>", {
            "text": ui.draggable.text(),
            "data-id": productid


        });


        //To remove item from other shopping chart do this
        var cartid = self.closest('.shoppingCart').attr('value');
        $(".shoppingCart:not(#" + cartid + ") [data-id=" + productid + "]").remove();

        self.html(listItem);

    }
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hirenwebdp/Ky8fP/8/

Comment: A fiddle is great, but please add your code to the question too. If jsfiddle is unavailable your question would be unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this click functionality to ur resetbutton...
[click here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ky8fP/13/)

```
    $(function(){
        $('#resetButtonId').click(function(){

         $( "ol li" ).empty();   
        }); 

    });
```